# Applying multiple layouts to same collection item in jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I have a jekyll collection `_persons`, with multiple peoples' profiles. Now I want to create multiple layouts for each person, e.g., a "Publications", and a "Bio" subpage for the same person.

How can I associate different layouts with the same person object? I'd also like to use sub-urls, such as:

- `\personA\publications\`
- `\personA\bio\`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that "bios" are the content type that you will be editing, you might create a symlink in your project root from `_bios` to `_publications`:

```
# Unix/Linux
ln -s _bios _publications
```

If you use windows, you'll need to check out `mklink`.

Then set up your config.yml like this:

```
collections:
  bios:
    output: true
  publications:
    output: true
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "_bios"
    values:
      layout: bio
      permalink: /biographies/:title/
  -
    scope:
      path: "_publications"
    values:
      layout: publication
      permalink: /publications/:title/
```

Edit markdown files for your people in the `_bios` directory, and do not specify layout or permalink in their frontmatter.

When your site builds, you'll get permalinks like `example.com/publications/personA` and `example.com/bios/personA`. You can loop through `site.publications` and `site.bios` as usual.

You'll need to define the `bio` and `publication` layouts, and these will have access to any data you define in the frontmatter of your `bio` collection items.

Credit for this idea: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3041#issuecomment-267730851

It might be more semantic to have a collection `_persons` as a single point of truth and make two symlinks from this collection.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not the person who asked the question, but I've tried it and can confirm it works. I get an error when running `bundle exec jekyll serve`: `** ERROR: directory is already being watched! **`, but it seems like this can be ignored.